# Can attacks be dodged?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

In Fire Emblem Heroes is it possible for a character to dodge an attack? "Normal" Fire Emblem games have hit accuracy listed before launching an attack, and some classes are designed around having high dodge rates. Are any of these mechanics included?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There does not seem to be an accuracy check on attacks in FE Heroes, so there is no way to dodge or evade attacks.

[This article](http://twinfinite.net/2017/02/fire-emblem-heroes-all-red-stone-character-heroes/) says that there is no accuracy mechanic in Heroes:

> As Fire Emblem Heroes doesn’t have accuracy rates like previous games, the triangle completely dictates how much damage characters will do.

This is also supported in [this article](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/what-is-fire-emblem-heroes-orbs/):

> In this Fire Emblem, attacks don't miss.